# How to import julia modules in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, julia

I am swifting from julia to python3. I know some useful modules of julia. I would like to know ***How to import julia modules in python?***

Comment: Derek's answer is useful, but it really does depend on what you're trying to do. If you're simply trying to avoid learning the equivalent python way of doing it, you may end up in more trouble this way. Equally, if you're simply trying to exchange data, you could simply have a pipeline of scripts which do not actually need to interact with each other in any way, other than access each other's generated data. Do not over-engineer a problem if it's not necessary. The introduction of extra dependencies alone is usually not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a python package that interfaces with julia if this helps

instructions here:

https://pypi.org/project/julia/